# CORINE land cover 2000: coordinate reference system

Tags: coordinate-system

The PDF in this link states that the CORINE land cover 2000 used ETSR89 as its coordinate reference system: http://www.eea.europa.eu/publications/technical_report_2006_7

I wanted to check I am reading this correctly: did CORINE 2000 use ETSR89 as its coordinate reference system?

In addition, what would be an appropriate coordinate reference system to re-project CORINE 2000 over the UK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The projected coordinate reference system is based upon ETRS89, yes. The projected coordinate reference system is EPSG:3035, ETRS89 / LAEA Europe, which you can find out by checking the [metadata](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/corine-land-cover-2000-clc2000-seamless-vector-database-4#tab-metadata) at the EEA. LAEA is an acronym for Lambert azimuthal equal area.

If I understand the technical report correctly, the LUCAS data was converted from ETRS89 to particular localized coordinate reference systems [to match CLC2000], perhaps before the CLC2000 data was combined into a single dataset?

Answer (score 4):

To answer the second part of your question regarding the correct projection for CLC over the UK, I would suggest you use [EPSG:27700](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/27700/).

For instance, assuming you have subset the data for the UK, you could then use [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) as follows:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "EPSG:3035" -t_srs "EPSG:27700" original_clc.shp output_clc_uk.shp
```